# Size of smallest PC/Mac executable?

Tags: html, macos, webview, chromium, tidekit

In TideKit:

1. How large is the smallest offline executable you can create for Windows respectively Mac including running HTML content in a web view? Other solutions like NodeWebKit include a portable Chromium, which makes the minimum package at least 25 MB.
2. What does the legacy support look like for Windows respectively Mac. What OS versions does it support for offline executables using web view for running HTML content?

Answer (score 0):

Tidekit offers options to build and package apps that affect the size of the runtime. First, TideKit will bundle only what it needs to keep the size of the runtime as small as possible. Builds allow you to optimize based on the requirements of your application, the platforms you wish to support, or to prioritize for things such as App Store compliance. Besides your code and our runtime, the resources you include contribute to the total size.

1. Packaging can involve bundling the runtime in the app or packaging
   the app with an installer that will only download a runtime when is
   not available on the host. Our runtimes are dynamic. The lightest
   scenario is network packaging with an installer that is
   auto-generated for you. Hello World can be bytes + the installer
   size. So perhaps 1 - 2 MB. In this scenario the host is checked for
   a runtime. If one is found, it will be checked for requirements of
   the app. If it has what it needs, there is nothing more. If the
   runtime on the host needs something it does not have, it will fetch
   it during the install. If there is no runtime, it is fetched during the install.

   Bundle installs include the runtime within the app and will make for larger apps. That      size will depend on what you are using. Application bundles could be as low as 15MB range for size. We'll be able to provide more specifics as we reach our release.
2. TideKit supports the following OS's on the desktop but supports web and mobile OS's so you can develop your app once and deploy for mobile, web, and desktop.

   - Windows XP
   - Windows Vista
   - Windows 7
   - Windows 8
   - OSX 10.6 Snow Leopard
   - OSX 10.7 Lion
   - OSX 10.8 Mountain Lion
   - OSX 10.9 Mavericks
   - Ubuntu 12.04
   - Ubuntu 12.11
   - Ubuntu 13.04